# Use of "language" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I do not think [language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) is a good tag. More specific tags should be used when possible.

Some tagging ideas can be found on https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags.

Comment: agreed. It's another [meta tag](http://meta.esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/6/48) - it will always be accompanied by more specific tags that describe the content better.

Comment: Said a user that used the tag "discussion".
*I do not think discussion is a good tag. More specific tags should be used when possible*
But anyways you're right there.. Language tag is too general. It's like using the tag Esperanto ;-)

Comment: @YotamSalmon [meta-tag:discussion] is one of the three tags questions on a meta site need to have. (The others are [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:support]). Without one of these tags, you cannot submit a question on meta sites.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Had to research before posting. I look so stupid now xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a [language] tag conveys no information about the *subject* of the question itself. We call this an *implicit tag* where virtually every question on this site can presumed to be to be about "language".

I will remove the tag, but first someone will have re-tag those questions with something more meaningful. We don't want to orphan those questions as [untagged].

*Update: The tag has been removed and will disappear overnight during the next automated cleanup.*

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks. Incidentally, the 'edit' button was disabled because those posts had pending suggested-edits.

Comment: Thanks!  I realized afterwards that that might be the case.

Answer (score -1):

Every question is about the language, when they aren't about the culture. I would think that [language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) is an implicit tag, since when you see a question tagged [verbs](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) you know the question is about the language.
I would say, let's not use [language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language), and use [culture](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) when the question is about Esperanto culture, rather than the language.

I edited the questions still using [language](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language). If the tag is not used in new questions, or old questions are edited to add it, the tag will be deleted in the next 24 hours.